# write a if line with a lot of exception using list

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have a lot of exceptions in a `if` line like this:

```
if "Aide" not in title and "Accessibilité" not in title and "iphone" not in title and "android" not in title and "windows" not in title and "applications" not in title and "RSS:" not in title:
    do_stuff()
```

How can I write this line to use a list ?

I've tried:

```
for a in ["Aide", "Accessibilité", "iphone" , "android", "windows", "applications", "RSS:"]:
   if title != a:
      do_stuff()
```

But this method calls `do_stuff()` for each `a`, so it's not what I would like...

How can I doing this ? Thanks

Comment: Add a `break` after `do_stuff()` to stop the for loop after the first match.

Comment: `if not(a in ["Aide", "Accessibilité", "iphone" , "android", "windows", "applications", "RSS:"]):` this would work. No need to iterate it.

Comment: @TanveerAlam that's not necessarily equivalent. I think the OP needs [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Then it has to be iterated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jonrsharpe's suggestion, you could do something like this:

```
titleList = ["Aide", "Accessibilite", "iphone" , "android", "windows", "applications", "RSS:"]
if all(title != x for x in titleList):
     do_stuff()
```

---

**Edit:**

Alternatively, this is much simpler (and it was Tanveer Alam who pointed it out):

```
if title not in titleList:
     do_stuff()
```

Why I didn't just write that out in the first place... will probably require some *very serious* soul-searching.

Comment: Both solutions are good, this one is more easier for me, using `all()`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could write something like:

```
def contains_any(s, it):
    return any(word in s for word in it)

if not contains_any(title, ["Aide", "Accessibilité", "iphone" , "android",
                            "windows", "applications", "RSS:"]):
    ...
```